# How can I model a non-continous threaded glass jar (lug finish) I'm having difficulty to do it

Tags: modeling, scripting, modifiers, edit-mode

How can I model a non-continous threaded glass jar (lug finish)

[image]

I'm having difficulty doing it. Is there any way to make it? I already spent so much time searching for the solutions but I can't find anything. Please help.

Answer (score 4):

If you care topology, it could be something like this ...

- add *Plane*, *Delete* Edge+Face, keep four vertices
- add **Screw modifier** - *Angle* 90, *Screw* according the height you need, use low *Steps* like 4 (it is easier to handle topology later ...

[image]

- **Extrude** up Z, *Scale* Z zero, do the same for the opposite side, Merge by Distance

[image]

- select "threads" in edge select mode and **Bevel Edge**

[image]

- Extrude in Normal direction

[image]

- Extrude inner part to give a thickness to glass neck and add add Subsurf modifier ...

[image]

- if you need sharpen "threads" connections to neck - select loops by shortcut and Bevel Edge (or use Shift+E+1 as non-destructive way)

[image]

[image]

[image]